# Effusion of Ideal Gas

Tags: thermodynamics

I just calculated that for an ideal gas inside a container, the average kinetic energy for molecules that are striking the walls of the container is larger than the average kinetic energy of the molecules comprising the entire gas.  Specifically, my result was $$\frac{E_{walls}}{E} = \frac{4}{3}$$ where $E=\frac{3}{2}T$.  I am pretty sure that this is correct.  My question is then if I have a container of gas in vacuum and I poke a hole in it, let some gas escape, and then close the hole before all of it escapes, am I right in thinking that due to my result above, the molecules that escape are more likely to have higher energy than the average energy of the whole gas, and as a result the energy and temperature of my system will have decreased?

Comment: The average kinetic energy of the molecules hitting the walls of the container is greater than the average kinetic energy of the molecules comprising the entire gas when the system is in thermal equilibrium? That doesn't sound right. Never heard of that before. Can you provide or reference a proof of that?

Comment: Landau and lifshitz statistical mechanics section 39

Comment: @SamuelWeir: the faster moving particles cross the container faster and therefore strike the walls more frequently than the slower moving particles.

Comment: @John Rennie - OK, I guess that if you look at the time rate at which molecules are hitting a particular wall (or exiting through a small hole in a wall), then the rate in molecules per second will be higher for the faster moving particles. From my misreading of the original question, I was picturing a sort of boundary layer near the walls of faster moving molecules.

Comment: Paul, note that for real gases at STP, even though they closely follow the ideal gas equation of state, the mean free path is a few microns. So for a real gas you'd never see this effect.

Comment: Back to the original question, I would think that the situation is similar to the cooling of a liquid by evaporation, in which excess energy is carried away by the more energetic molecules, leaving the less energetic ones behind. A practical problem would seem to be that the hole or holes have to be really small so that individual molecules are exiting the hole(s) and you don't just have a large-scale hydrodynamic flow of gas from the hole(s).

Comment: @SamuelWeir so does that mean that both the energy and temperature decrease (assuming a tiny hole)? I am almost certain about the energy but not so sure about the temperature.

Comment: @PaulMalinowski - Well, of course energy would decrease. It would decrease even if there were no fast-versus-slow molecule selectivity of the molecules leaving through the hole(s) since they all carry away energy. I would think that the average temperature of the system would decrease, too, because the rate of loss of fast molecules is greater than that of slow molecules. May be very difficult to see the effect experimentally, though, because it would seem to be a very small effect if you have a macroscopic container of gas and just one tiny hole for allowing individual molecules to escape.

Comment: In Landau & Lifshits volume 5, section 39, there are indeed three easy problems on the collision statistics using the Maxwell distribution to establish that the average kinetic energy of the molecule hitting the wall *per unit area and unit time* is equal to $ E_{\rm inc}=P\sqrt{\frac{2T}{\pi m}}$. Now, how does this compare to a kinetic energy at all ?

Comment: @tom-tom that's the total energy, not the average energy per particle

Comment: No, it's not. $E_{\rm inc}$ is, again, an energy per unit area and unit time. In a unit system where the temperature is expressed in energy units (for instance where $k_{\rm B}=1$ as in L&L), the dimension of $E_{\rm inc}$ is $\mathrm{[ML^{-1}T^{-2}\sqrt{ML^2T^{-2}/M}]=[MT^{-3}]}$, it is therefore neither an energy nor an energy per particle.